# check directory of oracle logs

Tags: oracle, nagios, command-substitution, file-monitoring

I'm using the check_logfiles nagios plugin to monitor Oracle alert logs. It works wonderfully for that purpose.

However I also need to monitor and entire directory of oracle trace logs for errors. This is because the oracle database is always creating new log files with different names.

What I need to know is the best way to scan an entire directory of oracle trace logs to find out which ones match patterns that specify oracle alerts.

Using check logfiles I tried specifying these options -

```
--criticalpattern='ORA-00600|ORA-00060|ORA-07445|ORA-04031|Shutting
 down instance'
```

and to specify the directory of logs -

```
--logfile='/global/cms/u01/app/orahb/admin/opbhb/udump/'
```

and

```
--logfile="/global/cms/u01/app/orahb/admin/opbhb/udump/*"
```

Neither of which have any effect. The check runs but returns ok. Does anyone know if this nagios plugin called check_logfiles can monitor a directory of files rather than just a single file? Or perhaps there is another, better way to achieve the same goal of monitoring a bunch of files that can't be specified ahead of time?

Comment: What is the point of checking for these errors as they are already reported in the alert.log file.

Comment: That's an excellent question! The alert logs are already well covered. I'll have to talk to the DBA about this and see what he says. I thought there was little point to checking the trace files. Thanks for confirming what I already thought I knew.

Answer (score 0):

Use a script which:

- Opens each file
- Copies entries which match the pattern
- Outputs the matches to a file